# TypeScript iterate string union type

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have:

```
class A {
 f():void{}
 g():void{}
}
const a = new A();

type AFunctions = "f" | "g";
```

I want to iterate AFunctions and produce new functions.
Similar to mapped types but with implementation and without manually writing all keys of course.

Pseudo code

```
const b: A = {
 for F in AFunctions add function F() {
   return a[f]();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do the new functions have the same signature as in `A` ? Or do they at least have the same signature signature between them ?

Comment: For simplicity they all have same signature () => void.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the properties of the class using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

```
function mapFunctions<T>(type: new (... params: any[])=> T) : { [P in keyof T] : ()=> void } {
    let mapped: { [name: string] : ()=> void } = {}

    let p = type.prototype;
    while(p !=  Object.prototype) {
        for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p)) {
            if(prop == 'constructor') continue;
            if(typeof p[prop] !== 'function') continue;

            mapped[prop] = ()=> {
                console.log(prop);
            }
        }
        p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p);
    }

    return <any>mapped;
}
class A {
    f(): void { }
    g(): void { }
}

class B extends A{
    h(): void { }
    i(): void { }
}
let ss = mapFunctions(B); // has functions f,g,h,i
```

Tying the type of the function to the result of the function on the origin object is more difficult, [Conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) and their associated [inference behavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496) in 2.8 will let you drill down to return type and argument types, but for now you could only use the full function type, such as `{ [P in keyof T] : ()=> T[P] }` (for a function with no parameters that return a function with the same signature as the original) or `{ [P in keyof T] : (fn: T[P])=> void }` (for a function that takes a function with the same signature as the original as a parameter)

Comment: Iterating over prototype is not bad 'let p = type.prototype;' , but I want a compile time simple solution. The compiler has the all data I need, it just needs to be exposed.

Comment: @NN_ I agree the compiler has all the info, it's just that it doesn't want to hand it over. I don't think there is a way force the compiler to give you the values for the names.

Comment: There is TS transformers which allows to generate such code. See: https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys

Comment: @NN_ Well, if you are willing to roll out your own custom compiler sky's the limit in terms of what you can do :)

Comment: Transformer is part of compiler API. You don't invent a new compiler. Btw here is the answer: https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys/issues/15

Comment: @NN_ I agree it's part of the API, you still need to customize your tool chain to use the compiler version with the included transformer, the stock compiler will not let you specify extra transformers (as far as I know). It's definitely an interesting solution and can be used, I'm just not sure I'd necessarily recommend it to everyone, but hey, it's your call, I'd definitely upvote if you provide the working solution as an answer to your own question :)

Comment: Here is a simple solution for this: https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript